# What is the relationship between boundedness and finiteness?

Tags: metric-spaces, terminology

Given a set $A$ in a metric space $(M,d)$ can someone clarify example just what is the relationship between a set being bounded and a set being finite?

> Does finite $\Rightarrow$ bounded or/and bounded $\Rightarrow$ finite?

Comment: Don't confuse  "the set is infinite" with "the set has infinite size/volume/extent/bounding sphere".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every finite set is bounded, because every finite set of real numbers (here, distances) has a maximum — there's a greatest member.

The unit interval $[0,1]\subseteq \Bbb R$ is bounded (yes?); is it finite?

The open-closed unit interval $[0,1)\subseteq \Bbb R$ is similarly bounded, but has no greatest member.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is bounded if there is some $r > 0$ and some $x\in M$ such that $A\subset B_r(x)$, where $B_r(x)$ is the ball around $x$ with radius $r$.

$A$ is finite if $A$ consists of a finite number of points (in $M$).

Of course, a finite set is bounded.